# Script working to pass POST var to PHP until filename change

Tags: javascript, php, xampp

any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. This is my first post. I've always been able to find answers from previous posts. I'm absolutely baffled now, so here it goes.

I have a simple script inside a html doc that sends a value to a php file that adds a few strings of text to a text file. The script sends the name of the page so I can count page hits. I haven't done any error catching, etc., I'm just trying to see how the basics work (I've programmed plenty, but I'm completely new to html, javascript, and php). Everything was working.

Then, I copied the php file, renamed it, and updated the script link with the new file name. No problem, right?--I just wanted a different file name than my test file name. sigh. With the new filename, the process isn't working.

I have the html file in a folder (like the Desktop). The php file is in a folder in XAMPP (I'm using Apache to simulate server). I've changed a few things, like adding COR allow to .htaccess file, and some other allowances. Again, all I did is try to copy the php file and rename it. You can see the filename is "numofhitscopy.php" When I copied the file and renamed it to "hitcounter.php and updated that in the link below, it stopped working. Here is the code...(the script is inside an html doc with the appropriate heading info. The php code is the exact same in both php files.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var param = 'value='+"home";
xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:80/Appeljacks/numofhitscopy.php', true);
//Send the proper header information along with the request
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send(param);
</script>

<?php
//Had to change php.ini file; below didn't work.
//date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$temp=$_POST['value'];
$dandt=date("Y-m-d h:i:s A");
$user_ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$fp = fopen("page_counter.txt", "a");
fwrite($fp,$user_ip.",".$temp.",".$dandt."\r\n");
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Typical output in page_counter file:

127.0.0.1,home,2021-12-16 12:18:16 PM
127.0.0.1,home,2021-12-16 12:22:49 PM
127.0.0.1,home,2021-12-16 12:22:51 PM

Comment: Put ALL your files in the htdocs folder under the XAMPP folder. Thats where the web server expects to find these things

Comment: Is there any error in the JavaScript console?

Comment: It was working even without all the files in the htdocs. But yes, I tried that because I thought that was the case and I initially missed that. But that didn't work--html and php files both in htdocs/subfolder.

Comment: If it's not failing to find the script, then the name shouldn't make a difference. Does your access log show that the script is being run?

Comment: @Barmar I deleted my previous comment. I AM getting an error! The Cross-Origin Request Blocked error. I thought I dealt with this. Why is this happening with the copied file with new name and not the old file?

Comment: Maybe something in .htaccess is checking the filename.

Comment: @Barmar This is all I have in .htaccess
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

Comment: Sorry, I know very little about Apache configuration, I don't know how to advise you. But if the filename makes a difference, there must be something in one of the config files that mentions the filename.

Comment: I added a couple of <Directory> statements to the httpd.config file, but for testing, I restored it to its original from the download. Still same problem. I can even run a similar form submittal that sends an email (using Mercury). Narrowing the problem, it seems xhr.send() is the main culprit causing a COR error, although I don't understand at all why the one file works and the other doesn't. Do these types of files or "information requests" get saved in the cache, and so at one point when it was working the system is just using something in the cache, but the new file is getting blocked?

Comment: SOLVED--But only PARTIALLY. I deleted the file named "hitcounter.php" I created a new file in Notepad++, pasted the code, saved as a new filename "pagecounter.php" It worked. Tried renaming the file, copying and pasting and renaming--all worked. However, as soon as I use the name "hitcounter.php" I get the COR error. Does anyone know why this would be? Is this a "special" name? Did I somehow corrupt my system and this name is banned, lol? Please, does anyone know what is going on? It's so curious.... (@Barmar @RiggsFolly--thank you)

Comment: There are no reserved names, although `index.html` and `index.php` are frequently used specially (they're the default if you try to access a directory without a filename).

Comment: All the information we have about the error so far, are really vague. Maybe you got some browser extension blocking something based on the word `hitcounter` in the URL ... Try in a private browser window without any extensions activated, and check if the problem also exists there.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, there is something blocking, but I can't figure it out. Firefox, Firefox Developer, Chrome, and Edge all are blocking the file name "hitcounter." MS Explorer popped up their "allow ActiveX...", and after clicking yes, it DID load it. And, all of them open "hitcounter" in Private/Incognito. So I feel the solution is near. What, how, why is this word being blocked? I apologize if I am being too vague. The code is extremely straight-forward, I'm using win10 with all updated browsers, most current version of xampp, etc. It's the filename somehow?

Comment: If this is useful, Firefox gives the error: Cross-Origin-Request-Blocked, and Chrome/Edge: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT. It's blocking the xhr.send(). I'm guessing these are pretty generic codes/info. I apologize for my ignorance. I'm working hard to understand anything and everything I can. Thank you to everyone.